# Make menu go away when an item is clicked on mobile/tablet

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

I have a pretty specific problem which i am hoping someone can guide me in the right direction with.
Here is the website link : http://rimowaedition.com/
When on a tablet or mobile device the menu is condensed into a button. To chose anything on the menu 
1. i have to click the button and it brings a drop down list. 
2. Click on the page i want to go to.
3. click the menu button to close the drop down list or else it takes up the whole screen and i cannot see the page in the back.

Here is a screenshot of how it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSk9b.jpg

Is there any way to make it so that when i click an item in the drop down it automatically closes the menu and goes to that page.
Any guidlines or clues as to how i would go about doing this would be much appreciated since as of now i am pulling my hair out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a click event on any item in the menu lists that you click.
So...
If you're using jQuery

```
$('list-item').click(function() {
    //Remove the class that causes the menu to be open
    //Perform any actions that you need after the button is clicked
    //such as loading another page 
});
```

This can also be done in vanilla javascript. Just search up click events in javascript.

Answer (score -2):

Use JavaScript Use JavaScript on the click event of any of the

```
> <a href>'s
```

in the menu to hide the menu.
 on the click event of any of the

```
> <a href>'s
```

in the menu to hide the meUse JavaScript on the click event of any of the

```
> <a href>'s
```

in the menu to hide the menu.
nu.